# How to access (use) passwords stored in MySQL myLogin.cnf

Tags: mysql, batch-processing, desktop-application, my.cnf, password-retrieval

I need to access the password stored in myLogin.cnf from a batch script and a desktop application's connection string. Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about it? My scripts and application work fine with hardcoded passwords, but...

I've tried using defaults-extra-file in my.ini, quotes around the password when entering mysql_config_editor set command, and other suggestions I've read, all to no avail.

My Setup is: Windows 10 running MySQL 8.0 (No Install)
Thank you

Comment: From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html): **To specify an alternate login path file name, set the `MYSQL_TEST_LOGIN_FILE` environment variable.**

Comment: I'm not allowed to vote yet. Although I haven't applied your answer yet, it put me on the right path and my problem is resolved. Thank you.